# Is it safe to use proxy?

Tags: kali-linux, proxy

I was reading [the article(Proxy-Risks)](https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-risks).

> you are vulnerable to identity theft, among other things. Hackers, the proxy webmaster and even the proxy owner can sell or use your data however they want, without your knowledge and not with your consent.
>
> Proxy providers, if they’re criminally minded, can also infiltrate your sessions with viruses and spam through a lot of pop-up advertisements, which you may inadvertently click or download.

Is it safe to set proxy autmatic? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about "the proxy owner"... Who is the owner of the particular proxy service(s) that you are using? What are you paying for their services? Or are they offering you their service for "free"? You may see an answer to your question if you ask yourself, What are those those "providers" getting out of the deal?

Comment: If something is free, then you are not the customer, but the actual product.